# Word cannot open DOCX file with a table

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to run mail merge against a DOCX file using Open XML API - just replacing a `<w:t>` element with a table (see below). Even the simplest table created using the following code results in Word erroring out when opening the file.

If I get rid of the row (so that I only have `<w:tbl>` / `<w:tblGrid>` / `<w:GridCol>`). there is no error, but then I cannot have any data of course.

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

```
Table table = new Table(new TableGrid(new GridColumn() { Width = "2000"}),
                        new TableRow(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("test")))))
                                      );
TextNode.Parent.ReplaceChild<Text>(table, TextNode);
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot replace `<w:t>` with `<w:tbl>`. The table is a block-level element so you can place it in the same places where you have the paragraph (<w:p>).

In other words, you can place it as a child element of one of the following: body, comment, customXml, docPartBody, endnote, footnote, ftr, hdr, sdtContent, tc, and txbxContent.

So, try something like this:

```cs
// TextNode (Text) -> Parent (Run) -> Parent (Paragraph)
var paragraph = TextNode.Parent.Parent as Paragraph;
paragraph.Parent.ReplaceChild(table, paragraph);
```

**EDIT:**

If the parent element is `<w:tc>`, you should add an empty paragraph to its end:

```cs
// TextNode (Text) -> Parent (Run) -> Parent (Paragraph)
var paragraph = TextNode.Parent.Parent as Paragraph;

var parent = paragraph.Parent;
parent.ReplaceChild(table, paragraph);

if (parent is TableCell)
    parent.InsertAfter(new Paragraph(), table);
```

Comment: Works fine as long as I also add a paragraph following the table - in my case, the table was inside another table cell, and Word threw a fit if there was no subsequent paragraph.
@Mario Z -  Where can I find any docs discussing this behavior? I have not seen anything discussing this.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko according to the [WPtableCell](http://officeopenxml.com/WPtableCell.php) specification, the only thing that's required is that a table cell must contain at least one block-level element. So, this seems to be a requirement specific to Microsoft Word. I tried opening such a document with different Word applications (like LibreOffice Writer) and they don't complain about the missing paragraph (but I did notice that some of them have weird cell rendering in that case).

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko just as an FYI, while experimenting a bit I noticed that the last block in the cell can also be an SDT element that contains a paragraph.